# Чтение и вывод файла excel в браузере

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю frontend есть такой index.js хочу в нем прочитать файл excel

```
import xlsx from 'node-xlsx'
let workBook = xlsx.parse('./resources/goods.xlsx');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Но при старте в браузере выводится такое:

```
TypeError: _fs.readFileSync is not a functionread_binary
```

На скрине подробнее, помогите плиз понять почему и как с этим справиться?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоп стоп, вы смешиваете разные вещи. node и веб, в данном случае они не совместимы. У вас же обычная страничка `html`, к который вы через браузер обращаетесь? Или же это проект на каком-нибудь Electron

Comment: Проект на React

Comment: ну так, а где проект будет выполняться? В браузере? Это обычная веб страничка? в таком случае там в принципе не доступны модулю `node`

Comment: то есть node чисто серверный на клиенте его модули не выполняются?

Comment: нет, не выполняются

Comment: node - не "чисто серверный", но для браузера он не предназначен. Если вы хотите выводить excel в браузере, вам нужен сервер на node (включая node-xlsx) и фронтенд (напр. на React) - _**отдельно** от сервера.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909260/reading-excel-file-in-reactjs вот здесь пример ридера excel-файлов

Comment: в принципе понял, только вот вопрос в примере там тоже подклюяается библиотека и она работает, почему не все модули работают?

Comment: @hindmost оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Comment: @Alexandr Tovmach Да как-то неудобно).. это же неполноценное решение. так, просто совет.

Comment: @hindmost Ваш совет содержит правильный ответ, поэтому никаких проблем + [тут флешмоб](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8646/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: @Alexandr Tovmach _Ваш совет содержит правильный ответ.._ Это не совсем так. У ТС похоже типичный случай "XY problem" и мой совет касался конкретной библиотеки. Но с другими библиотеками проблема сервера отпадает. В общем я дополнил свой совет и оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js сам по себе используется преимущественно на сервере и совершенно точно не предназначен для браузера. Так что если вы хотите выводить excel в браузере с помощью библиотеки [`node-xlsx`](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx), то, помимо вашего фронтенда на React, вам необходим сервер на Node.js с установленным `node-xlsx`, т.к. этот модуль работает ***только на сервере***.

Впрочем, в общем случае для задачи вывода excel в браузере сервер необязателен. Так, в состав `node-xlsx` входит библиотека [`js-xlsx`](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), которая как раз может работать ***без сервера***. `js-xlsx` предлагает два способа чтения excel файлов без сервера: [`FileReader` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (для современных браузеров) и AJAX-запрос (для старых браузеров). Ниже пример чтения excel файла с помощью `FileReader` API:

```
function handleFile(e) {
  var files = e.target.files, f = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
    /* Вывод содержимого workbook в браузер */
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
input_dom_element.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);
```

Другие примеры чтения с excel файлов в `js-xlsx` можно найти [здесь](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#parsing-workbooks).